# delay the loading of PHP/jQuery Wordpress plugin until contents are loaded

Tags: css, wordpress, load, element

i'm placing a shortcoded PHP/jQuery ticker into the very top of my home page, and it appears unformatted & ugly for a couple of seconds before it falls into place as the content completes loading (the page loads quite quickly, but still... right?)

i read here that there are ways to delay the jQuery from loading until the content is loaded, but what i'm trying to achieve is for the entire horizontal ticker to not even appear until it's properly formatted by the CSS.

is this at all possible? does it matter in which order the CSS elements are loaded as far as output?

thanks for any of you geniuses help. :)

GN

[EDIT] >>
ok, i can see how unclear that was. "Glenn Posts", Take Two:

my html ticker is full screen width, 30px high, while the ticker content div within is much, much longer. It's masked with a *div.mask CSS width: X, overflow:hidden* rule set. The problem is, until these particular values are applied, the very long string of Post titles (ticker content) is visible and doubles or triples the height of the ticker element on the page. it only lasts for a second, but i don't like it being visible like that at all.

I'm just hoping that there's a way to either hide it all until **all** the CSS is applied - or - just whatever i could do to make the .mask values load before other ones, maybe...? am i asking the right question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to reference your css before your javascript in your header.  For inline style and scripts in the body, the same rule applies: css first, then scripts.

If not, you can use the jQuery ready method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // do what you want here
});
```

[jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: I wanted to hide the whole thing until it was fully loaded. thanks to you, (and jQuery) this did it! thanks!

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery( ".latest_newsarea" ).removeClass( "hid" );
});